# How do I take the mean on either side of a value in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, interpolation, mean

I have a Pandas DataFrame where the index is datetimes for every 12 minutes in a day (120 rows total). I went ahead and resampled the data to every 30 minutes.

```
                 Time  Rain_Rate
1 2014-04-02 00:00:00       0.50
2 2014-04-02 00:30:00       1.10
3 2014-04-02 01:00:00       0.48
4 2014-04-02 01:30:00       2.30
5 2014-04-02 02:00:00       4.10
6 2014-04-02 02:30:00       5.00
7 2014-04-02 03:00:00       3.20
```

I want to take 3 hour means centered on hours 00, 03, 06, 09, 12, 15 ,18, and 21. I want the mean to consist of 1.5 hours before 03:00:00 (so 01:30:00) and 1.5 hours after 03:00:00 (04:30:00). The 06:00:00 time would overlap with the 03:00:00 average (they would both use 04:30:00). 
Is there a way to do this using pandas? I've tried a few things but they haven't worked.

Comment: split the dataframe into chunks of the desired time range, and then take the mean of each chunk. Probably worthwhile to read their page on [indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html). It's hard to say how you specifically should do it, but if it's arbitrarily complex you can [filter by your own function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-callable), but most likely [boolean indexing will be fine](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Method 1

I'm going to suggest just change your `resample` from the get-go to get the chunks you want.  Here's some fake data resembling yours, before resampling at all:

```
dr = pd.date_range('04-02-2014 00:00:00', '04-03-2014 00:00:00', freq='12T', closed='left')
data = np.random.rand(120)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=dr, columns=['Rain_Rate'])
df.index.name = 'Time'
```

```
#df.head()
                     Rain_Rate
Time                          
2014-04-02 00:00:00   0.616588
2014-04-02 00:12:00   0.201390
2014-04-02 00:24:00   0.802754
2014-04-02 00:36:00   0.712743
2014-04-02 00:48:00   0.711766
```

Averaging by 3 hour chunks initially will be the same as doing 30 minute chunks then doing 3 hour chunks.  You just have to tweak a couple things to get the right bins you want.  First you can add the bin you will start from (i.e. 10:30 pm on the previous day, even if there's no data there; the first bin is from 10:30pm - 1:30am), then `resample` starting from this point

```
before = df.index[0] - pd.Timedelta(minutes=90) #only if the first index is at midnight!!!
df.loc[before] = np.nan
df = df.sort_index()

output = df.resample('3H', base=22.5, loffset='90min').mean()
```

The `base` parameter here means start at the 22.5th hour (10:30), and `loffset` means push the bin names back by 90 minutes.  You get the following output:

```
                     Rain_Rate
Time                          
2014-04-02 00:00:00   0.555515
2014-04-02 03:00:00   0.546571
2014-04-02 06:00:00   0.439953
2014-04-02 09:00:00   0.460898
2014-04-02 12:00:00   0.506690
2014-04-02 15:00:00   0.605775
2014-04-02 18:00:00   0.448838
2014-04-02 21:00:00   0.387380
2014-04-03 00:00:00   0.604204  #this is the bin at midnight on the following day
```

You could also start with the data binned at 30 minutes and use this method, and should get the same answer.*

### Method 2

Another approach would be to find the locations of the indexes you want to create averages for, and then calculate the averages for entries in the 3 hours surrounding:

```
resampled = df.resample('30T',).mean() #like your data in the post

centers = [0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21]

mask = np.where(df.index.hour.isin(centers) & (df.index.minute==0), True, False)
df_centers = df.index[mask]

output = []
for center in df_centers:
    cond1 = (df.index >= (center - pd.Timedelta(hours=1.5)))
    cond2 = (df.index <= (center + pd.Timedelta(hours=1.5)))
    output.append(df[cond1 & cond2].values.mean())
```

Output here is the same, but the answers are in a `list` (and the last point of "24 hours" is not included):

```
[0.5555146139562004,
 0.5465709237162698,
 0.43995277270996735,
 0.46089800625663596,
 0.5066902552121085,
 0.6057747262752732,
 0.44883794039466535,
 0.3873795731806939]
```

*You mentioned you wanted some points on the edge of bins to be included in both bins.  `resample` doesn't do this (and generally I don't think most people want to do so), but the second method I used is explicit about doing so (by using `>=` and `<=` in `cond1` and `cond2`).  However, these two methods achieve the same result here, presumably b/c of the use of `resample` at different stages causing data points to be included in different bins.  It's hard for me to wrap my around that, but one could do a little manual binning to verify what is going on.  The point is, I would recommend spot-checking the output of these methods (or any `resample`-based method) against your raw data to make sure things look correct.  For these examples, I did so using Excel.

Comment: Yes this worked! Thank you so much! I used the first method. I realized the reason I thought the bins had to overlap was because I had already resampled them to 30 minutes. By leaving them in the 12 min periods, I don't have to worry about overlapping bins.